# Show a series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that the series
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\pi+\pi n^2)}{n} $ converges.

i tried expanding in e and double angle identity i also tried to bound it but that is 1/n which doesn't converge.

Comment: Why did you abandon formatting in the second paragraph? Seems lazy to me. And what in the world is "expanding in e" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2):

So $\left\{\dfrac{\sin((1+n^{2})\pi)}{n}\right\}_{n}=\left\{0,0,...\right\}$.

Comment: Isn't $\sin(k\pi)=0$ for any natural number $k$? and $1+n^2$ is a natural number for any $n=1,2,3\cdots$.

Comment: Sorry I kind of overlooked, I thought it is cosine.